# How can I make an Office 365 Group auto accept calendar meeting invites

Tags: calendar, office-365-groups

I am the owner of an Office 365 group.  I would like to make that group automatically accept meeting invites.  How can I do that?  I'm fine with accomplishing this via the GUI, PowerShell, CSOM, or any other mechanism.